# Google indexing wrong domain that does not work

Tags: google, google-index

Can anyone tell me why Google indexes a site http://0.3c.7aae.static.theplanet.com instead of the actual domain name (my domain was registered with webmaster tools).

The aforementioned link was linking to my site, but has now become a broken link. 
Initially I tried 301 directs, but nothing worked.

The hosting company cannot explain why. Leaving me wondering what to do? 
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thks

Answer (score 1):

*If you take a look at your name servers:*

http://host.robtex.com/ns2.hostinginmind.com.html#records you can clearly see this is on their network. What's happened at some point in DECEMBER 2012 your site was operating on that domain. Now the problem seems fixed as `http://0.3c.7aae.static.theplanet.com` no longer works. It may take a couple of weeks for Google to catchup. Personally I'd contact Google as there's nothing you end you can do unless you have ownership of `theplanet.com`....

If own theplanet.com do a move site request.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, much appreciated. This is a great forum.

Comment: Site move requests via Google Webmaster Tools only work for changing a domain name.  They don't allow a webmaster to move a site from a subdomain on one domain name to a full domain name.  So that tool won't work in this case.